# Random predefined background color and text color on 2 divs

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

I am looking to create a Jquery script that will randomly choose a colour from a list of 10, and then apply it as a background color to one div, and the color of a h1 tag.

So far I have this which makes a random color:

```
$(document).ready(function() { var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ','
                 + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ','
                 + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
$('#controls-wrapper').css("background-color", hue);
$('h1').css("color", hue);});
```

but how can I make this choose randomly from a list of 10 colors?
I found this, but not sure how you would apply this to bg color div and h1 tag.

```
$("#controls-wrapper").each(function(){ 
var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"]; 
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length); 
$(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]);});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is this:

Assuming you have a HTML page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <div id="controls-wrapper>some text</div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $('#controls-wrapper').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
  $('h1').css("color", colors[rand]);
});
```

After you have created your colors array you then get a random number corresponding to the index of a color.

Now that you have a random index you can use it to set the background-color, or text color of an object.

If you wanted the colors to be different for each then you would just call

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
```

again before setting the color of your next element.

And finally by calling `$('h1').css("color", colors[rand]);` you will set the color on all H1 elements on the page, you want it to be specific set an ID or class value on the H1 and then use `$('h1.myclass').css("color", colors[rand]);` OR `$('#ID_for_my_H1').css("color", colors[rand]);`

Comment: Many Thanks, that is the same answer that I got to as well. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help:
[Changing colors of a DIV](http://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/BoRMba)

Here is the JS of the code for an overview of approach that i used!
JS:

```
setInterval(function () { 
  document.getElementById("fancy").style.background= '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.body.style.background= '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); 
}, 1000);
```

Though this post is little old but it may be of some use in context of this question!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.random-color {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  color:#CC00CC;
}
<a class="random-color" href="#">
  Link 1
</a>
<a class="random-color" href="#">
  Link 2
</a>
<a class="random-color" href="#">
  Link 3
</a>
<a class="random-color" href="#">
  Link 4
</a>
<a class="random-color" href="#">
  Link 5
</a>

var randomLinks = $('a.random-color');
var original = randomLinks.css('color');
var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099", "#1295A6", "#FFFF99"]; 
randomLinks.hover(function() { //mouseover
    var col = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
    $(this).css('color',colors[col]);
    $(this).animate({
        'paddingLeft': '20px'
    }, 1000);
}, function() { //mouseout
    $(this).css('color',original);
    $(this).animate({
        'paddingLeft': '0'
    }, 500);
});
```

Try this using link http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpby

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["orange", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green"];
var colorNumber = Math.round((Math.random() * (array.length - 1)));
$("body").css('background-color', array[colorNumber]);
```