# How do i make my background change on refresh?

Tags: jquery, css, background

Hi i was wondering if there was a code or query that allows my background to change on every refresh, as well as the background color with the background as well

Take a look at this site http://www.youngblackstarz.org

Notice that on every refresh the background changes and the background color coordinates with it too.

How is this done can anyone help me figure this out?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3):

demo: http://demos.9lessons.info/bgchange/index.html

bgimages
-- 1.jpg
-- 2.jpg
-- 3.jpg

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var totalCount = 8;
function ChangeIt()
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.background = 'bgimages/'+num+'.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
// Page Design
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
ChangeIt();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The informations here can help you.

http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/simple_two_line_image_randomiser_script_with_jquery

[JQuery Random Background color and color, on 2 div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897573/jquery-random-background-color-and-color-on-2-divs)

Comment: This is precisely what can be a very efficient way to do that .. :) thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using Javascript

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function changeBackground() {



    var new_date = new Date();
    var no_of_imgs = 7;
    var no_of_second = new_date.getSeconds();
    var bal_no = no_of_second % no_of_imgs;
var bg_img ="";

    if (bal_no == 0)
{

    bg_img ='<div class="template_row bg_img_a" id="main_content_pane">'; 
    }
    if (bal_no == 01)
{

    bg_img ='<div class="template_row bg_img_e" id="main_content_pane">';       

    }
    if (bal_no == 02)
{       

    bg_img ='<div class="template_row bg_img_g" id="main_content_pane">';
    }    

 if (bal_no == 03)
{

    bg_img ='<div class="template_row bg_img_d" id="main_content_pane">';

    } 

 if (bal_no == 04)
{       

    bg_img ='<div class="template_row bg_img_b" id="main_content_pane">';

    } 

 if (bal_no == 05)
{       
    bg_img ='<div class="template_row bg_img_f" id="main_content_pane">';

    } 

 if (bal_no == 06)
{

    bg_img ='<div class="template_row bg_img_c" id="main_content_pane">';       

    } 

//Print the relevant Div here   
document.write(bg_img);
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      changeBackground();
    });

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

var totalCount = 2;

    var num =  Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    document.body.background = 'assets/background-'+num+'.jpg'; 
    });
```

I have tidied up the code a bit. The count is 2 at the minute.

File will go into http://www.yoursite.com/assets/background-1.jpg

Upload each image and increase number and totalCount for how many you want.

For Wordpress change 'assets' to 'wp-content/uploads/yy/mm/filename-NUMBER.jpg'

Hope this helps