# change background color and hover colors on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

I want to change the website logo color and the hover color of the buttons every time a user refreshes the pages. The colors have to be coordinated. [Website Link](http://brava.cf)
The logo is actually an image with a transparent region, where I can put any background color I want.

Someone had a similar problem here: [JQuery Random Background color and color, on 2 div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897573/jquery-random-background-color-and-color-on-2-divs)

This is the javascript that I made based on that thread:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var colors = ["#fda65f","#66CCFF","#71e271","#D37AFF"];                
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
   $('#logo').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
   $('.cbp-ig-grid').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

.cbp-ig-grid changes the background color properly, but I want the color to appear only on hover. The .cbp-ig-grid class has this hover property:

> .cbp-ig-grid li > a:hover {
>       background-color:#71e271;}

The problem is that if I change the javascript code '.cbp-ig-grid' with '.cbp-ig-grid li > a:hover' it stops working. I have no experience with Javascript, so I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would be more inclined to print out a `<style>` sheet using javascript than add `hover()` events using jquery

```
<script>
var colors = ["#fda65f","#66CCFF","#71e271","#D37AFF"];                
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
var head = document.head,
    style = document.createElement('style');

var css = '#logo { background-color: ' + colors[rand] + '; } ';
    css += '.cbp-ig-grid li > a:hover { background-color: ' + colors[rand] + '; } ';

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `hover()` method :

```
$('.cbp-ig-grid').hover(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it works with                                         $('.cbp-ig-grid li').hover(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]); 
});     but now after hovering, the color remains active. What can I do so the hover effect stays only on mouse over?
});

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.cbp-ig-grid  li > a').hover(function(){
$(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is this:

replace  `$('.cbp-ig-grid').css("background-color", colors[rand]);`

with `$('.cbp-ig-grid li > a:hover').css("background-color", colors[rand]);`

is that correct?
anyways, you can't control the hover state with a jQuery selector: `$('.cbp-ig-grid')`

you can achieve this by setting a event handler with a function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var colors = ["#fda65f","#66CCFF","#71e271","#D37AFF"];                
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
   $('#logo').css("background-color", colors[rand]);

   $(".cbp-ig-grid li").on("mouseover", function () {
       $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
   });

}
```